# What is $opt variable for command line parameter in bash

Tags: bash, command-line

I have below bash script, I am a bit confuse about what is $opt meaning. and I do not find detail information about it after search.

test.sh:

`echo "opt:" $opt
for opt; do
        echo $opt
done`

output:

`./test.sh -a -b c
opt:
-a
-b
c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [bash(1) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> ```
>    for name [ [ in [ word ... ] ] ; ] do list ; done
>           The list of words following in is expanded, generating a list of
>           items.  The variable name is set to each element of this list in
>           turn, and list is executed each time.  If the in word  is  omit‐
>           ted,  the  for  command  executes  list once for each positional
>           parameter that is set (see PARAMETERS below).  The return status
>           is  the  exit  status of the last command that executes.  If the
>           expansion of the items following in results in an empty list, no
>           commands are executed, and the return status is 0.
> ```

So, if the `in` word is missing the for loop iterates over the positional arguments to the script, i.e. `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ....

There is nothing special about the name `opt`, any legal variable name can be used. Consider this script and its output:

```
#test.sh
echo $*    # output all positional parameters $1, $2,...
for x
do
    echo $x
done

$ ./test.sh -a -b hello
-a -b hello
-a
-b
hello
```

Comment: Why did you rollback? I fixed all the problems your code has: lacks of quotes that make it subject to pathname expansion: did you try `./test.sh '*'`?. Use of `echo` is completely broken in this case; you really must use `printf` here: did you try `./test.sh -n`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf -  Thanks for your interest, but while you are correct, I wrote it this way to be consistent with the OP's question so that the difference is clear. The code is there only to illustrate to the OP that `opt` is not a predefined variable. I think it's clearer this way. Your point could be made as an additional answer (I think comments would be inadequate in this case).

Comment: If you believe you can leave broken code online (without even mentioning it's broken) for future generations to dig, fine, but I have the opposite point of view. Anyways, this question is not going to have too much traffic so it's not really a big deal. I just don't understand why there are so many answers that don't also address the obvious other mistakes that are in the OPs. People would learn so much more if these were also discussed and solved!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf -  In general I agree with you, and to be honest, I didn't consider the problem that you cited. Here I'm trying to answer the question that was asked, not perform a code review. As I already suggested, you can post an answer of your own if you think it worth pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

the `for` statement goes generally like this:

```
for x in a b c; do
  ...
done
```

`$x` has the value `a` on the first iteration, then `b`, then `c`.
the `a b c` part need not be written out literally, the list to iterate through can be given by a variable, like the `$@`, which has the list of all arguments to the current scope:

```
for x in "$@"; do
  ...
done
```

further, `in "$@"` is *assumed* if you provide no list explicitly:

```
for x; do
  ...
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`$opt` is not a built-in or special variable. If it's mentioned in the script (outside of `for opt` without the `in something` part, which [@mhawke already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28780092/96588)) it should either be defined earlier in the script or it's expected that it is [`export`ed](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Variable_Types) before running the script.